# Swing: How to kill worker threads if main window is closed?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

So I have a swing application, a button, when pressed, will launch a worker thread. If the main window is closed it the JVM is still running with the worker thread going on uninterrupted and indefinitely. I want the worker thread to die when the window is closed.

Comment: Have you tried [`SwingWorker.cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel(boolean))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the entire application to terminate when the window is closed you can use this:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

If you just want to stop the worker thread only and maybe do other stuff. You can register a WindowListener on the frame and in the onWindowClosing callback, you can check the event type and do whatever you wish.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. As pointed out by Tomasz, the JVM will exit when ALL non-daemon threads die. This will simply as the JVM to exit when all said threads have finished

Answer (score 1):

JVM exits when all non-daemon threads die. Your worker thread is not a daemon, thus not allowing JVM to exit. Just let worker [thread to be *daemon*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29):

```
workerThread.setDaemon(true);
```

Another approach is to [`interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) your thread when closing the main window, but that requires handling of [`isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) and `InterruptedException`.